# How to count the same label rows in array with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a following array in table structure. I want to count the same age for it and put the result in an array with Javascript. Could anybody give me a hint how to do this?

Array in table form:

```
Name Country Age
lucy China   20
mark Japan   30
lili Korea   20
jack Japan   21
```

Expected array table:

```
Age Count
20   2
21   1
30   1
```

In code type:

```
[
['Age', 'Count']
['20', 2]
['21', 2]
['30', 1]
]
```

Comment: If you want a hint then my hint is [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). The example [Counting instances of values in an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Counting_instances_of_values_in_an_object) seems like what you need

Comment: none of your code blocks is valid javascript. Please provide a valid source, expected result and what you tried yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a function which takes in a 2D array and the index of the column to group by.
- Get an array without the header row by using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the resulting array.
- Get the value of the specific index by [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the parameter.
- Create an accumulator object with each unique value as key. Increment the key if it already exists, else set the value to 1.
- Use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the key and count value pairs. Add the `[<column name>, "Count"]` to the beginning of the output array

This works for any index of the array.

```js
const input = [
["Name", "Country", "Age"],
["lucy", "China", 20],
["mark", "Japan", 30],
["lili", "Korea", 20],
["jack", "Japan", 21]]

function groupColumn(array, index) {
  const merged = input.slice(1).reduce((acc, { [index]: value }) => {
    acc[value] = acc[value] + 1 || 1;
    return acc;
  }, {});
  
  const columnName = array[0][index];
  
  return [[columnName, 'Count'], ...Object.entries(merged)]
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(groupColumn(input, 2))) // Age
console.log(JSON.stringify(groupColumn(input, 1))) // Country
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Array looks like that, that you could use the following solution.

```js
var array1 = [['lucy','China',20], ['mark','Japan',30], ['lili','Korea',20], ['jack','Japan',21]]

var result = array1.map(x => x[2]).reduce(function (acc, curr) {
  acc[curr] ? acc[curr]++ : acc[curr] = 1;
  return acc
}, {});


console.log(result);
```

[Array​.prototype​.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

[Array​.prototype​.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.